# Why do we see an inverted image in a spoon on the concave side?

Tags: optics

Actually I already read the answer given but that is not satisfactory. The real image is always inverted and virtual image is always erect. But we see a virtual inverted image. How is this possible? Please answer my question as early as possible.

Comment: When you get an inverted image in a concave mirror, the image is real. Why do you think it's virtual?

Comment: For that I am sorry. But I forgot that I posted the question. That is why I posted it again.

Comment: And March if it is a real image then why is it seen without a screen?

Comment: Real simply means that it is *possible* to project it on the screen. It doesn't mean that it must be on a screen. And if it *is* on a screen it must be real.

Answer (score 0):

Is their a link to your previous answers - I've no clue why they were not helpful.

If you get close enough, the curvature becomes unimportant, you are just looking into mirror. This is a virtual image that cannot be projected onto a screen, a direct reflection. The light rays never pass through the image location behind the mirror so it is virtual.

Further away beyond the spoon's focal point for the spoon's curvature a real, project-able image that is inverted is created.

(Perhaps try drawing a ray diagram instructions here, although these seem a bit wordy
http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refln/Lesson-3/Ray-Diagrams-Concave-Mirrors)

Comment: If the image is real then how can it be obtained without a screen? That is why I think it is a virtual image.

Comment: You are using a screen  in your eye, the retina. (with some optics in between)

Comment: But how is it seen inverted.

Comment: it is a virtual image. But in a concave mirror only in one case the image formed is virtual which is erect. Why is the image inverted?

Comment: please answer it as soon as possible.

Comment: One light path is from the top of the object to the top of the spoon, reflects through the focal point to the bottom of your eye.

Comment: Another light path is from the bottom of the object to the bottom of the spoon, reflects through the focal point to the top of your eye.

Comment: All the light in between follows the same rules, parallel light arriving above the focal point is reflected through it, and onwards below it. This inverts the image.

Comment: I am unable to understa image nd. If that image is real then it should be obtained on a screen. How is this possible that the image is inverted but is seen on the mirror, though only virtual can be seen on a mirror. If you want to say that the image is virtual, Then it should be erect and not inverted. And if you are saying that the screen is our retina it is because of the eye lens and not the mirror. We see the image on the mirror. Please tell me the exact reason.

Comment: there are two different types of image depending upon whether you are closer to the spoon than the focal point.
If you are closer you see the virtual erect image. If you are more distant you see the real inverted image (the light rays crossed, creating a different image).
Both images are there all the time.

Comment: yes that is why I am saying. We see an inverted image in the spoon. But we should see only an erect image in the mirror. Why we see an inverted image in the mirror?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand that problem. We see an erect image in a mirror and in a spoon if we are close enough to it. The spoon makes another image aswell that is different, which you only see when you are further away.

Comment: No no I am not talking about that. My question is that how we see an inverted image inside the spoon though it is real?

Comment: We should obtain it on the screen and not on the mirror.

Comment: It is possible to see both real and virtual images because in both cases the light arrives at your eyes.

Comment: actually I want to post an image.